# How to pass a variable data to createFragementContainer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

I´m using Relay Modern to build my component and I want to pass a varible to the fragment so that it can be used as a GraphQL argument on my query.

Here is the code I´m using:

```
class Test extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
       userId: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }

    render = () => {

        return (

            <p>User Id: {this.props.userId}</p>
            <p>User name: {this.props.viewer.name}
        );
    }
}

export default createFragmentContainer(
    Test,
    graphql`
        fragment Test_viewer on Viewer {
            user(id: $userId) { <<=== The $userId must be the this.props.userId passed
                id
                name
            }
        }
    `
);
```

When issuing the query GraphQL server returns error saying `Variable \"$userId\" is not defined by operation \"UserQuery\"."`.

My query in the parent component:

```
const UserQuery = graphql` 

  query AdminQuery {
    viewer {
      ...Test_viewer
    }
  }
`
```

How can I make the code above work ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your variable at the query level:

```
const UserQuery = graphql` 
  query AdminQuery($userId: ID!) {
    viewer {
      ...Test_viewer
    }
  }
`;
```

When using this query on a `<QueryRenderer />` element, you will also pass the variables as prop:

```
<QueryRenderer
  query={UserQuery}
  variables={{
    userId: 'USER_ID',
  }}
  // ... others props
/>
```